# Assign nested Product/Tuple to Array[Numeric]

Tags: scala

I am looking for a fast way to assign a Product to an Array with type Numeric. For instance I want to fill the *array* elements with *values*:

```
// not restricted to be 4-by-2, can be abritary
// Double will be later replaced by type T : Numeric
var elements = new Array[Double](4*2) 
// can contain other Numemrics as Int
var values = ((11.0,12.0),(21.0,22.0),(31.0,32.0), (4.0,1.0))
```

My approach so far is

```
var i = 0;
var itRow = values.productIterator.asInstanceOf[Iterator[Product]]
while(itRow.hasNext){
    var itCol = itRow.next.productIterator.asInstanceOf[Iterator[Double]]
        while(itCol.hasNext){
            elements(i) = itCol.next.asInstanceOf[Double]
            i = i + 1
        }
}
```

It works if all entries in values are Double, but it would be nice to get this working for abritary Numerics too.
Second, is there a more ellegant and faster way to do this? Maybe it would be better to flatten the Tuple by

```
def flatProduct(t: Product): Iterator[Any] = t.productIterator.flatMap {
    case p: Product => flatProduct(p)
    case x => Iterator(x)
}  

// edit: I think this is better, 
// but still the problematic if there are Int-types in values
flatProduct(values).asInstanceOf[Iterator[Dobule]].copyToArray(elements)
```

What to you think?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

take your pick:

```
scala> values.productIterator.map{case (x: Double, y: Double) => Array(x, y)}.flatten.toList
res17: List[Double] = List(11.0, 12.0, 21.0, 22.0, 31.0, 32.0, 4.0, 1.0)

scala> values.productIterator.asInstanceOf[Iterator[(Double,Double)]].foldLeft(List[Double]()){(l, i) => i._2 :: i._1 :: l}.reverse
res18: List[Double] = List(11.0, 12.0, 21.0, 22.0, 31.0, 32.0, 4.0, 1.0)

scala> values.productIterator.foreach{var i = 0; {case (x: Double, y: Double) => elements(i) = x; elements(i + 1) = y; i += 2}}

scala> elements
res19: Array[Double] = Array(11.0, 12.0, 21.0, 22.0, 31.0, 32.0, 4.0, 1.0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! I am sorry, that my description was not clear enough. The prolem is, that the tuple is not restricted to be 4-by-2 and not restricted to be Double (but the Array is Double)

Comment: in that case, your flatProduct method is good. just add `.map(convert).toArray` after calling it, where `convert` is a function `Any => Double`. Since it is an iterator, everything is done in one pass (when converting to the array)